# Using WPF in IIS7 or a windows service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, iis-7

We currently do a fair amount or dynamic image generation of png's in ASP.NET using the GDI+ classes in .Net with a no major issues. I had hoped to take advantage of many of the new drawing, FormattedText, RenderTargetBitmap, optimization algorithms, etc. in WPF in our ASP.NET application, but apparently this is not supported and came to a grinding halt with .Net 3.5sp1 ([WPF running under IIS no more](http://www.ktsc.com/blogs/ChristopherKeslin/?p=12) and [connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=361469)). We we are running Server 2008 x64.

I understand that "technically" GDI+ wasn't supported in ASP.NET applications but it does work and there are even commercial offerings available that are built on it.

So my question is whether anyone is successfully using WPF in an ASP.NET or Windows Service application? Does anyone have any suggested workarounds or alternatives?

Comment: WPF doesn't use GDI+.  It uses DirectX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Microsoft are working on a fix:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1299963.aspx

How long until it's ready?... No idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, it should be possible I think. I know you can use the WindowInteropHelper class to get the Handle to a WPF window. The rest should be about the same you'd think.

Comment: According to this https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=361469 there is an issue and none of the workarounds work on 2008 x64.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with a company that is using WPF in an IIS hosted renderer, though you have to have a hotfix from Microsoft installed.
My understanding is that this hotfix is not publicly available, but is likely to be released in December.